# ESP32 Arduino can't connect to NodeJS SocketIO web socket - Solved

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, arduino, esp32

I'm trying to connect my ESP32 with my local Nodejs server via web socket.
I'm using PlatformIO Arduino environment on CLion (I don't know if it's useful to know).

The ESP32 manages to connect to the WiFi, it can also read the content of the server page (I did it as a test), but it seems to be unable to connect to the SocketIO websocket, I searched everywhere without finding anything, I hope you can help me.

ESP32 Code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

WebSocketsClient websocket;
boolean connected = false

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
    switch(type) {
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
            Serial.printf("[WSc] Disconnected!\n");
            connected = false;
            break;
        case WStype_CONNECTED: 
            digitalWrite(MESSAGE_LED_PIN, HIGH);
            Serial.printf("[WSc] Connected to url: %s\n", payload);
            connected = true;
    }

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin("SSID", "PASSW");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Connesso al WiFi");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    inviaRichiestaHTTP(); // I don't enter the code of this function
    websocket.begin("192.168.1.16",3000,"/socket.io/?EIO=4");
    websocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
}

void loop() {
    websocket.loop();
}
```

Serial:

```
....
Connesso al WiFi
192.168.1.170
[HTTP] Codice di stato: 200
<h1>Hello world</h1>
[WSc] Disconnected!
[WSc] Disconnected!
[WSc] Disconnected!
```

Nodejs Server:

```
const ip = require("ip");
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server); //pass a http.Server instance
var port = process.env.PORT  80;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //check sender ip
    var senderip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for']  req.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log('sender ip: '+senderip);
   res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Client connected');
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log('Message received: ', data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
});

server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a different file header:

> <s><WebSocketsClient.h></s> **<SocketIOclient.h>**

Then I simply followed the [documentation](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets) and the [example](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/blob/master/examples/esp32/WebSocketClientSocketIOack/WebSocketClientSocketIOack.ino)